# PHP Papal SDK - list of transactions

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Just trying get list of all incoming transactions to our PayPal account with PayPal PHP SDK, but result from following example return me still just one record (and we have thousands of payments in our live environment). According PP documentation everything looks ok... Is there any different service for incoming payments?

```
<?php 

// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        '...SUssUIJQ6zEOdQBI7nUG...',     // ClientID
        '...YHw3aCroq0mbqSdzimPq...'      //Secret hash
    )
);
$apiContext->setConfig(array('mode' => 'live'));


$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();

try {

    $params = array();
    $payments = $payment->all($params, $apiContext);
    echo $payments;
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    print_r($ex);
}
```